# Locale reverts to old locale after exiting root?

Tags: command-line, root, locale

Heyo~

I am having an issue whenever I change locale. At present, I am getting this error whenever I run the locale command.

> locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
>
> LANG=
>
> LANGUAGE=en
>   en
>
> LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
>
> LC_NUMERIC=en
>
> LC_TIME=en
>
> LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
>
> LC_MONETARY=en
>
> LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
>
> LC_PAPER=en
>
> LC_NAME=en
>
> LC_ADDRESS=en
>
> LC_TELEPHONE=en
>
> LC_MEASUREMENT=en
>
> LC_IDENTIFICATION=en
>
> LC_ALL=

After entering root using 'sudo -i' or 'sudo su', I use 'export LC_ALL="en_GB"'. Using locale whilst in root gives this.

> LANG=
>
> LANGUAGE=en
>   en
>
> LC_CTYPE="en_GB"
>
> LC_NUMERIC="en_GB"
>
> LC_TIME="en_GB"
>
> LC_COLLATE="en_GB"
>
> LC_MONETARY="en_GB"
>
> LC_MESSAGES="en_GB"
>
> LC_PAPER="en_GB"
>
> LC_NAME="en_GB"
>
> LC_ADDRESS="en_GB"
>
> LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB"
>
> LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB"
>
> LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB"
>
> LC_ALL=en_GB

However, after leaving root, via 'exit', 'reboot' or simply closing the Terminal, the changes completely revert and the "locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory" error returns. The output of 'locale' is the same as before I used 'export LC_ALL="en_GB"'

I've attempted to use 'dpkg-reconfigure locales' to no effect.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Doing `export LC_ALL=`, whether in root or not, you set locale for *the current process* (and its descendants), not for *the operating system.* You’re in the Unix world ☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your locale is a complete mess.

- Please go to "System Settings -> Language Support".
- Drag the language of your choice to the top, and click "Apply system-wide".
- Move to the "Regional Formats" tab, select the region of your choice, and click "Apply system-wide".
- Reboot.

Hopefully that does it.